# Correct way of adding HttpClient PUT parameters? - Porting TypeScript REST call to C#

Tags: c#, rest, typescript

I'm partially porting a TypeScript application to C#. The application needs to perform a certain REST call on a webservice. The webservice is written in C# and the specific method has the following signature:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterDevice(DeviceRegistration deviceRegistration)
```

The original application (TypeScript) makes the REST call in the following manner:

```
this.$http.put(this.Configuration.registrationEndpointUrl, {
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2,
    field3: value3
})
```

I searched StackOverflow on how to do the call and found a post explaining how to do it. I then created the following in the C# version:

```
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("field1", Settings.Value1),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("field2", Settings.Value2),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("field3", "value3")
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
var response = await Client.PutAsync(Configuration.RegistrationUrl, content);
```

However this just returns an empty response. I'm thinking something is wrong with the `FormUrlEncodedContent`? What is the correct way of doing this call in C#?

EDIT: Client initialisation code:

```
private static async Task<HttpClient> CreateClient() {
     await Authenticator.VerifyAuthentication();
     var client = new HttpClient();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-zumo-auth", Settings.OAuthToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-oauth-provider", Settings.OAuthProvider.Value.ToString());
    return client;
}
```

Comment: What is the status code of the response?

Comment: @Vyrira BadRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the method

```
var response = await Client.PutAsync(Configuration.RegistrationUrl, content);
```

You can use this

```
var response = await Client.PutAsJsonAsync(Configuration.RegistrationUrl, content);
```

Comment: The `PutAsJsonAsync` method does not appear to exist for me. I'm using .Net Framework 4.5 which I believe should have it?

Comment: Your Client is of type HttpClient?

Comment: Yes, I've added the client initialisation code to the question.

Comment: Are you sure the framework version is 4.5? 

See my version: Assembly System.Net.Http
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll

Comment: I seem to have fixed this by adding the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet package which adds the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` that appears to hold this method. This method looks to be the cleanest way of executing the put and works well, so I'll accept this answer,

Comment: You can add the version System.Net.Http 4.5. What is your version of VS?